# Plot two lists with different length

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have two lists with different prices. The first list is for the years 2008-2018 and the second for the years 2010-2018. How I can plot them under the condition that the years 2008 to 2018 are on the X-axis and the second list starts in 2010?

I have the following as an example of a short code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

Geb_b30 = [11, 10, 12, 14, 16, 19, 17, 14, 18, 17]
Geb_a30 = [12, 10, 13, 14, 12, 13, 18, 16]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(Geb_b30, label='Prices 2008-2018', color='blue')
ax.plot(Geb_a30, label='Prices 2010-2018', color = 'red')
legend = ax.legend(loc='center right', fontsize='x-large')
plt.xlabel('years')
plt.ylabel('prices')
plt.title('Comparison of the different prices')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to accept an answer ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I have forgotten to accept one. Your answer works very good, so I use that one.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I suggest you to simply define the x values (i.e. the list of years) for each set of points, and to pass them in parameters of `ax.plot()`, as follows:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

Geb_b30 = [11, 10, 12, 14, 16, 19, 17, 14, 18, 17]
years_b30 = range(2008,2018)
Geb_a30 = [12, 10, 13, 14, 12, 13, 18, 16]
years_a30 = range(2010,2018)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(years_b30, Geb_b30, label='Prices 2008-2018', color='blue')
ax.plot(years_a30, Geb_a30, label='Prices 2010-2018', color = 'red')
legend = ax.legend(loc='center right', fontsize='x-large')
plt.xlabel('years')
plt.ylabel('prices')
plt.title('Comparison of the different prices')
plt.show()
```

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yes of course. There are only 10 prices in the input list `Geb_b30`, so it goes from 2008 to 2017 included, that is why I used `range(2018,2018)`.

Comment: I'm sorry for being snarky. I miscounted myself. Fixed my own code now. Vote flipped of course.

Answer (score 5):

IIUC, just pad your missing years with `None`/`NaN`:

```
import pandas as pd

years = list(range(2008, 2018))
Geb_b30 = [11, 10, 12, 14, 16, 19, 17, 14, 18, 17]
Geb_a30 = [None, None, 12, 10, 13, 14, 12, 13, 18, 16]
df = pd.DataFrame({"years":years, "b30": Geb_b30, "a30": Geb_a30})

df.plot(x="years")
```

[image: plot]

Comment: That doesn't necessarily produce the desired effect. While it may work in some cases, introducing spurious data is generally not a good idea.

Comment: Replace the data with Nan instead and I would agree that you're reproducing the intended result

Comment: Ok, fair enough - updating

Comment: I liked the image though :)

Comment: imgur is telling me it's broken...working on it.  also, you're totally right - zeros are completely wrong here.  was just moving too quickly.  thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 4):

To tell matplotlib where you want points to end up on the x-axis, you must explicitly provide the x-values. The size of the x-axis values must correspond to the size of the y-values, but there does not need to be any relationship between sets of independent data, as you've already seen.

```
Geb_x = range(2008, 2018)

...

ax.plot(Geb_x, Geb_b30, label='Prices 2008-2018', color='blue')
ax.plot(Geb_x[2:], Geb_a30, label='Prices 2010-2018', color = 'red')
```

Comment: What are you converting `Geb_b30_x` to `list` for? Both your solutions work fine even without converting to `list` or using `np.arange`.

Comment: @Bazinga. Fixed the first one. The second one should be pretty clear.

Comment: I mean if you just write `years = range(2008, 2019)` and then use `years[2:]`, it still works. No need of `np.arange`.

Comment: @Bazinga. I see. Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

you should create a new list containing your years.
Then you can specify where on the x-axis you want to plot by odoing years[10:18] for instance

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

Geb_b30 = [11, 10, 12, 14, 16, 19, 17, 14, 18, 17]
Geb_a30 = [12, 10, 13, 14, 12, 13, 18, 16]

years = list(range(2008,2018))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(years[0:len(Geb_b30)],Geb_b30, label='Prices 2008-2018', 
color='blue')
ax.plot(years[2:],Geb_a30, label='Prices 2010-2018', color = 
'red')
legend = ax.legend(loc='center right', fontsize='x-large')
plt.xlabel('years')
plt.ylabel('prices')
plt.title('Comparison of the different prices')
plt.show()
```

EDIT: Updated with correct x-axis

Comment: That x-axis is even less correct now. Range 2008 is an enormous sequence containing almost none of the numbers of interest up to 2018. Try running your code.

Comment: Please run your code before posting. Now you have an outright syntax error.

Comment: Again, thanks, and yeah you're right. was a bit hasty.

Comment: And now we all have the same answer :)

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways you could achieve this. One elegant way would be to use pandas. This way you automatically get correctly labelled and aligned x ticks.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

geb_b30_x = pd.date_range(start="20080101", end="20180101", freq="A")
geb_b30_y = [11, 10, 12, 14, 16, 19, 17, 14, 18, 17]
geb_b30 = pd.Series(data=geb_b30_y, index=geb_b30_x)

geb_a30_x = pd.date_range(start="20100101", end="20180101", freq="A")
geb_a30_y = [12, 10, 13, 14, 12, 13, 18, 16]
geb_a30 = pd.Series(data=geb_a30_y, index=geb_a30_x)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(geb_b30, label='Prices 2008-2018', color='blue')
ax.plot(geb_a30, label='Prices 2010-2018', color = 'red')
legend = ax.legend(loc='center right', fontsize='x-large')
plt.xlabel('years')
plt.ylabel('prices')
plt.title('Comparison of the different prices')
plt.show()
```