# Shift plots of different lengths in the same x-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a very specific something I want to do with matplotlib I don't even know if it's possible, but I figured it was worth asking. Maybe the answers will give me an alternate idea about how to go about it.

I have 4 arrays of similar, but different lengths that I want to plot in the same x-axis. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51726509/python-plot-two-lists-with-different-length) question suggests creating the values for x using `range()`, and it worked:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6), dpi=300)
x_5 = range(len(all_data_float[0]))
plt.plot(x_5, all_data_float[0], color='b', marker='.')
x_10 = range(len(all_data_float[1]))
plt.plot(x_10, all_data_float[1], color='r', marker='.')
x_15 = range(len(all_data_float[2]))
plt.plot(x_15, all_data_float[2], color='g', marker='.')
x_20 = range(len(all_data_float[3]))
plt.plot(x_20, all_data_float[3], color='c', marker='.')
plt.show()
```

But I wanted to do something else, I want to plot a vertical line in the middle aligned by a point, for example there are 4 plots with:

- plot1: 101 points
- plot2: 99 points
- plot3: 100 points
- plot4: 101 points

So for plot1, that point would be index 51, which means 51 points before and 49 after with the line crossing point 51. For plot2, that middle point is index 49, which means 49 points before and 50 after, and so forth.

My difficulty is that the vertical line has a different index for each plot. I know `plt.vlines()` accepts an array, but in this case it plots multiple lines, and I wanted a single line.

Is there a way to "shift" each plot relative to the x-axis? so index 51 of plot1 aligns with index 49 of plot2, etc? Or is there a better strategy to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the set up of the question I am going to assume that the the x-values do not have any numerical meaning so it is safe from a data-point-of-view to shift them around.  Instead of plotting your data against `range(len(...))`, do the shift there!

```py
import matpoltlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def synthetic_data(length):
    "make some variable length synthetic data to plot."
    return np.exp(-((np.linspace(-5, 5, length)) ** 2))


data = [synthetic_data(51), synthetic_data(75), synthetic_data(105)]


fig, ax = plt.subplots(constrained_layout=True)

for d in data:
    x_vector = np.arange(len(d)) - len(d) // 2
    ax.plot(x_vector, d)

ax.axvline(0, color="k", ls="--")
ax.set_xlabel("delta from center")
ax.set_ylabel("synthetic data!")
```

[image: shifted curves]

Comment: Yes, only the order of points matter in this plot. Your suggestion worked nicelly! Thanks! Learned something new about python :)